# Can I set a default value for an arbitrary argument in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I set a default value for an arbitrary argument in python? If yes, how to do that...
I tried:

```
def printf(age, gender, *fave, name = "veronica"):

    print(name, " ", gender, " ", age, " ")
    print("favefood: ", end = "")
    for i in fave:
        print(i, end = " ")

printf(25, "f", "water", "grass")
```

and I got the output as:

```
veronica   f   25  
favefood: water grass
```

now I want to set a default value for  *fave, something like

```
printf(age, gender, *fave = "grass", name = "veronica")
```

then I received an error message saying "invalid syntax". So I was wondering if I could really do this for an arbitrary argument...

Comment: It's  not recommended to place variable arguments in between generic arguments else you can have name as keyword argument. Please refer to my answer for more details

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as an accepted answer. This will help the people facing the same issue as yours in future to know which was the solution that the requester found it best. This is just to help the community become more better

Answer (score 2):

### No You Can't

The entire purpose of `*args` is so that you can send 0 arguments to it without an error:

```
def f(*args):
    print(args)
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

f("foo", "bar", "baz")
print("----------------")
f()
print("----------------")
f("Hello", "World")
```

Output:

```
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
foo
bar
baz
----------------
()
----------------
('Hello', 'World')
Hello
World
```

***How ever you can just use an if statement***

```
def f(*args):
    if args == (): args = ("default value")   ## <--- Here
    print(args)
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not like that, but you can define your function like this:

```py
def printf(age, gender, *fave, name = "veronica"):
    fave = fave or ["grass"]
    print(name, " ", gender, " ", age, " ")
    print("favefood: ", end = "")
    for i in fave:
        print(i, end = " ")
```

The output would be:

```
printf(25, "m", name="john")
john   m   25  
favefood: grass
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a 'No' and 'Yes' answer. Ideally you are not meant to have defaults for *args. This is because variable arguments are used when you are not sure of how many arguments are passed (could be 0 too, as suggested by Yash's answer).

If you seriously need a workaround you can check for a null value (`None` in python) and assign a value for that argument/variable using a simple ternary snippet like below

```
fave = fave if fave else "grass"
```

I do have couple of suggestions. It is always recommended to have varargs (*args,*kwargs) at the end of your argument list. In your case you are having another argument called 'name' at the end which is not recommended standard. You need to have your arguments something like below:

```
def my_func(arg1,arg2,arg3,*args,**kwargs)
```

Else you can have 'name' as a keyword argument instead of a normal argument. So you can have your function signature like either of the below ways:

```
def printf(age, gender, name = "veronica", *fave)

def printf(age, gender, *fave, **kwargs)
```

Please read more about python's variable arguments [here](https://stackabuse.com/variable-length-arguments-in-python-with-args-and-kwargs/)